# Buffer Analysis Problems

Tags: python-2.7, arcmap

My attribute table has a field named "FEATURE", inside of this contains two feature classes, Airport and Seaplane Base. I am trying to create two buffers, a 15000 meter around Airplane and 7500 meter around Seaplane Bases.

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "E:\Python Programming\Lab5a"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, ["FEATURE"], '"FEATURE" LIKE \'%Airport\'', "15000 METERS")
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, ["FEATURE"], '"FEATURE" LIKE \'%Seaplane Base\'', "7500 METERS")
```

This does not work at all and fails to execute tool.

Answer (score 0):

First off your file path is wrong.

```
env.workspace = r"E:\Python Programming\Lab5a" the r stands for raw string
```

Basically you have to escape the backslash. Your current string doesn't make the path you think it does.